# How to make dynamic query filter run in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I need to prepare a solution to create a parameterized solution to run different filters. For example: I am currently using below query to apply filter on a dataframe but

```
input_df.filter("not is_deleted and status == 'Active' and brand in ('abc', 'def')")
```

Need to change this approach to build this query from configuration:

```
  filters_to_apply = {'table_name' : 'input_df',
    'rule_1' : 'not is_deleted',
    'rule_2' : 'status == "Active"'
    'rule_3' : 'brand in ("abc", "def")'
                              }

filters_to_apply['table_name'].filter(' and '.join([(filters_to_apply[key]) for key in filters_to_apply.keys() if 'rule' in key]))
```

I am getting error as : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'filter'

Please could you advice

Comment: you can  try wrapping key name in col function

Comment: So, in this case, is `input_df` a table registered in the current spark context?

Comment: yes input_df is a spark dataframe that contains columns is_deleted, status and other columns. Idea is to create a function that will take dictionary containing table name and filters and return the filtered dataframe so we keep the filters in configuration file and call the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is important to understand why you are getting this error.

The way the dictionary `filters_to_apply` is defined, it is mapping string keys to **string** values. Having a defined variable named `input_df` has nothing to do with a **string** with the characters `"input_df"`. For Python, they are two completely different things.

As far as I know, you have two alternatives here:

1. You can pass the variable `input_df` (assuming it is defined somewhere) around and apply the filters directly on it (you can have a function in which one of its arguments is a DataFrame, so it can handle different DataFrames).
2. With the defined variable `input_df`, you can register a [temporary view](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView) and [retrieve](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.table) the same DataFrame later.

### My suggestion

Define a function whose arguments are composed of a DataFrame and a sequence of rules.

Example of a function definition:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from typing import Iterable

def my_filter(df: DataFrame, conditions: Iterable[str]) -> DataFrame:
    return df.filter(" and ".join(conditions))
```

Example of usage:

```
df = sparksession.createDataFrame(
    [(1, True, "Active"), (2, False, "Active"), (3, True, "Disabled")],
    ["id", "bool", "status"]
)
df.show()

my_filter(df, ["not bool", "status = 'Active'"]).show()
```

Results:

```
+---+-----+--------+
| id| bool|  status|
+---+-----+--------+
|  1| true|  Active|
|  2|false|  Active|
|  3| true|Disabled|
+---+-----+--------+

+---+-----+------+
| id| bool|status|
+---+-----+------+
|  2|false|Active|
+---+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, configuration should look as below, that is input_df should not be a string

```
  filters_to_apply = {'table_name' : input_df,
    'rule_1' : 'not is_deleted',
    'rule_2' : 'status == "Active"'
    'rule_3' : 'brand in ("abc", "def")'}
```

But, if you have registered input_df as temp table then definitely you can pass it as a string. I mean as below:

```
input_df.registerTempTable("input_df")
```

Assuming you have registered it as temp table, one of the way to do that could be as follows:

```
def prepare_data(config):
   df = spark.table(config['table_name'])
   for key in config.keys(): 
      if key.starts_with("rule_"):
         df = df.filter(config[key])
   return df
```

Also, if you want to lean more about how to automate your codes, refer to this link - https://youtu.be/KBRPUDovzmc